# Create Calendar events via Tasker that starts when entering a location and ends when leaving it

Tags: tasker

I want to use tasker to log how much time I spent at a location.
I would like tasker to create a calender entry when I enter a location and have the end of the calender event be when I leave the location.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer: Yes.

What you didn't ask: How :)

Have a location-based profile which fires when you reach the location in question. In the entry-task, create the first calendar entry ("Entered [location]"). Then, add an exit-task – in which you create the second calendar entry ("Left [location]").

You might have to add some checks to compensate for "drops" (e.g. entering the basement of a building might drop you to de-facto "airplane mode" with no cell network, no WiFi network, and no GPS coverage – which might "accidentally drop you out of the location"). So the exit task should contain something like setting a variable with the "current time", then a loop for e.g. 10 times having a *Tasker › Wait › 10 seconds* and location re-check, and then only log the "exit" when you really "left the building".

---

If you wish a single calendar item with the start time set to the locations entry, and the end time to when you exit it, a little modification is required:

- in the entry-task, set a variable holding the current (entry) time
- in the exit task, when submitting the calendar item, use the variable's content for the start, and the second variable's content for the end time of the event.

Answer (score 0):

If your willing to try [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate), another automation app. Here's a flow for it:

http://llamalab.com/automate/community/flows/14